# Significance of conformal image of a real axis being a circle

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

In the course of analyzing linear response of some electrical and mechanical systems, I noticed that the complex plot of their impedance,i.e.parametric plot of impedance with frequency as a real-valued parameter, is often a circle. The examples of such plots are shown in the image:
[image]
The neccessary condition seems to be that there should be a pole away from the real axis. On the other hand the function (impedance vs. frequency) does not have to be rational.

I am curious what is the mathematical/physical significance of ubiquitousness of the circle?

Comment: We can consider the complex numbers as a subset of the Riemann sphere, which is basically the complex numbers with a point at infinity added, so that this point is the north pole of a sphere, while $0$ is its south pole. Lines and circles in the plane are circles on this sphere. Apply any transformation which preserves circles on the sphere to get a transformation which maps lines to either lines or spheres. I don't know why the maps you are interested in belong to this class of functions, but at least it's a start to understand the connection between the real axis (a line) with circles.